# Axiomatic Set Theory, Successors

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Assuming that $\omega$ is the the minimal inductive set.
Let $x\neq 0$ be an element of $\omega$. Then $x=y^+$ for some unique $y\in \omega$.

This would seem to be intuitive as every every $x\in \omega$, $x$ has only one successor, namely $x^+$ defined by $x^+ = x\cup \{x\}$. So for some unique $y\in \omega$ define $x= y\cup \{y\}$, then $x=y^+$? How can I show that $y$ is unique in $\omega$?

Comment: In $\omega+\omega$ every element also has a successor, yet not all non-zero $x$ have a predecessor. You must invoke the definition of $\omega$ as the *minimal* inductive set for this.

Comment: I am assuming that to be the case. I suppose I should have mentioned that in the question. That said, does my logic work as proof?

Comment: No, I gave a counterexample to the logic: your argument is incomplete. How do you know $y$ exists? If it does , unicity is the next problem.

Comment: I have amended the question to assume  ω as the minimal inductive set.

Comment: You don’t get to define $x$ in terms of $y$. $x$ is given and **fixed**, and then you are supposed to show that there exists a $y$, which depends on $x$, such that $x=y^+$.

Comment: **Hint:** Consider the set $A\subseteq \omega$ that consists of all $x\in\omega$ such that either $x=0$ or $x=y^+$ for some $y\in\omega$. Prove that $A$ is inductive. Then prove that if $y,z\in\omega$ are such that $y^+=z^+$, then $y=z$.

Comment: I am quite lost with this problem but I will give that a try. Thank you.

Comment: Axiomatic Set Theory, comment on your title.

Comment: @RhettSchroers Why did you change the tag back to [set-theory]? That tag is meant for advanced problems, this questions fits in the [elementary-set-theory] category.

Comment: $( y^+=z^+ \land y\ne z)\implies$ $ (y\cup \{y\}=z\cup \{z\}\land y\ne z)\implies$ $ (y\in z\land z\in y). $